# 1. Azure Monitor: Forbidden: AuthorizationFailed. With running and testing Azure monitor in Grafana

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-monitoring

I keep getting the below error when I try and save and train my Azure monitor which will act as a data source for my dashboard in Grafana.

> 1. Azure Monitor: Forbidden: AuthorizationFailed. The client '----------' with object id '----------' does not have authorization
>      to perform action
>      'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read' over scope
>      '/subscriptions/--------'.

I have entered my subscription ID, Tenant ID, and Client ID, as well as my Client secret. But for some reason keep getting this error.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: The error clearly indicates that you don't have permission to list the resource groups. You will need to contact your Azure administrator to grant proper permissions.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error means your service principal(AD App) does not have the permission `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read` to the scope.

To fix the issue, navigate to the subscription or the specific scope in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search your service principal with name and add it as a role(e.g. `Owner`/`Reader`) -> `Save`.

Or if you don't what to add your service principal as a bulit-in role,  you can [create a custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) with the permissions you need, then add the service principal as a custom role in the resource(scope).

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal). Lean more about azure role-based access control (RBAC), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview).